# What does JaCoCo rule elements mean and how to combine them

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm trying to understand JaCoCo rules but there are not many great examples around. Every thread I see circulates the same examples from the [docs](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html#rules).

I see 3 different metrics:

- element types (BUNDLE, PACKAGE, CLASS, SOURCEFILE or METHOD)
- limits (INSTRUCTION, LINE, BRANCH, COMPLEXITY, METHOD, CLASS)
- values (TOTALCOUNT, COVEREDCOUNT, MISSEDCOUNT, COVEREDRATIO, MISSEDRATIO)

I understand that *"element types"* represent the scope of each rule, fair enough.

- BUNDLE: That represents the project as a whole
- PACKAGE: Each java package
- CLASS: As name states, a single class
- SOURCEFILE: How is this different than the `CLASS`? Does this have to do with inner classes?
- METHOD: Scope is for each method

Now though, how limits and values come into scope? For example:

```xml
<limit>
    <counter>LINE</counter>
    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
    <minimum>80%</minimum>
</limit>
```

can I replace `LINE` with `INSTRUCTION` for example? And if *yes*, what does this mean?

Also from the docs:

> If a limit refers to a ratio it must be in the range from 0.0 to 1.0 where the number of decimal places will also determine the precision in error messages.

`RATIO` vs `COUNT` is clear, but can I use them interchangeably? i.e:

```xml
<limit>
    <counter>LINE</counter>
    <value>TOTALCOUNT</value>
    <minimum>3</minimum>
</limit>
```

and if *yes*, what does the above rule mean?
From a generated report, `INSTRUCTION` and `BRANCH` are always on *ratio*
[image: jacoco report]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, a part of this question regarding `BUNDLE, SOURCEFILE`, and `CLASS` just got [answered here](https://groups.google.com/g/jacoco/c/X4n1iF7wTRA/m/DNI8BQ0_AQAJ) in the JaCoCo groups.

Essentially,

- BUNDLE - All classes in the Maven module combined together will be checked against the rule
- SOURCEFILE - Each Java file will be checked against the rule
- CLASS - Each Class file will be checked against the rule

The confusion starts for `SOURCEFILE` and `CLASS`, but you need to understand that a Java file can have multiple classes. For example, here is `Shape.java` which has 2 classes - `Shape` and `Triangle`.

```java
public abstract class Shape {
}

class Triangle extends Shape {
}
```

`SOURCEFILE` will check the rules against `Shape.java`, while `CLASS` with check the rule against both `Shape` and `Triangle`.

For instance, here is a rule configuration

```xml
<rule>
    <element>SOURCEFILE</element><!-- Here I change it for SOURCEFILE and CLASS values -->
    <limits>
        <limit>
            <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
            <value>TOTALCOUNT</value>
            <maximum>1</maximum>
        </limit>
    </limits>
</rule>
```

Below is the output for `SOURCEFILE` config.

```
[WARNING] Rule violated for source file io/codejournal/maven/jacocodemo/Shape.java: instructions total count is 6, but expected maximum is 1
```

When you run the same thing with `CLASS` config, the output is for each class separately.

```
[WARNING] Rule violated for class io.codejournal.maven.jacocodemo.Triangle: instructions total count is 3, but expected maximum is 1
[WARNING] Rule violated for class io.codejournal.maven.jacocodemo.Shape: instructions total count is 3, but expected maximum is 1
```